# Grammarly browser plugin not working on web-based Jupyter notebook files

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, plugins, jupyter-lab, grammarly

The Grammarly browser plugin provides useful editorial hints when editing a text area on the webpage; for example, I am getting help while typing this question here.

However, when accessing a notebook file hosted on the Jupyter Lab server on the `localhost`, the Grammarly browser plugin does not engage. While access any other website with the same browser is OK.

I have tested with Chrome and Firefox, and the result is the same.

I followed the [Firefox troubleshooting steps](https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000090392-I-do-not-see-the-G-icon-on-a-certain-web-page-or-in-a-certain-text-field-but-see-it-on-other-web-pages) on Grammarly's official website, but all checking results came back as OK, which means Grammarly was not disabled.

So, I wonder whether I am missing something about Grammarly usage in this scenario. I appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Comment: It should in principle work with JupyterLab 4 and Notebook v7 which uses new CodeMirror 6 editor, but (code?) cells are marked as `spellcheck=false` to avoid highlighting every line of code as a potential error. I would give a most recent pre-release a try and if it requires a way to switch `spellcheck` attribute, opening a feature request on JupyterLab GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, @krassowski. I just checked and verified that the Grammarly plugin doesn't engage regardless of the cell type; let it be either "Raw", "Code", or "Markdown". By the way, where to check the `spellcheck`? And is it possible to configure or modify the source code for a proof of concept?

Comment: Was that in the latest alpha of JupyterLab 4? I am not sure where the change in code need to be applied because the commit history in related PR was overwritten via force pushes, but it worked in all cells as of https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/11638#issuecomment-1170288854 (you can ping the author of the PR to ask how they addressed disabled spellcheck/Grammarly on GitHub). As for making changes the contributing documentation is at: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer/contributing.html